# container apps preview - container revision provision failed - No error information provided

Tags: azure-container-apps

Azure container apps preview, revision provisioning status failed but no error messages are available.  **How do I diagnose the problems with provisioning?**

- Log Analytics has no tables long after provisioning, and no queries return data.
- Container image is from an Azure Container Registry.
- Verified that the container image does work from a container instance.
- The quick start image works okay.

[image: Failed provisioning]

Comment: I've been playing with it for 2 days now. Looks like the product isn't nearly finished by now!